# jquery: IE7 won't prepand a label to the corresponding inputs div-container

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7, javascript

I want to make sure that the structur of my form is like that:

```
<form>
    <div>
      <label>
      <input>
    </div>
<form>
```

I use jquery to catch the label from whereever it is and move it between `<div>` and `<input>`.
This works fine in Firefox but IE has problems with that. How can I get it running with IE?

Here's the line that causes errors in IE6 and IE7:

```
var inputname = $(this).attr('name');
$(this).parents('form').find('label[for='+inputname+']')
       .prependTo($(this).parent('div.slidebeyond-div'));
```

Thank you!

Comment: What happens in IE?  Does the <label> element get moved somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question: how are you verifying that the  element is not being moved?**

When you run the code in FF, the `label` element gets moved to directly below the `div`  You can verify this with Firebug.

When you run the code in IE the label also gets moved to the right spot.  If you use **view source** to inspect the DOM you are only seeing the DOM before all of your jQuery did its thing.

**Edit** I am also assuming that the code you have supplied is within a:

`$('input').each(function(){});`